# How to make announcments for GIS.se?

Tags: discussion, announcements

As evidenced by the relatively low level participation on meta.gis thus far, not many people from the main site are taking the time to visit here. When there are questions for the broader community (domain name, contests, etc.), how are we to catch their eyeballs?

Answer (score 2):

On stackoverflow the area on the right is used for advertisements.

I guess ads won't appear in GIS.se until it's out of beta(?)

Perhaps until then we could run ads that entice people to participate in meta.GIS.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a Q on GIS saying "hey, please come over here a moment and talk about X" is technically possible but doesn't feel right. If we decide this is the least evil method after all and do it anyway, I'd delete the question after N days.

Comment: That would be inappropriate and closed as off topic. I agree that meta participation is too low but we'll have to come up with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the low participation is due to interface I think. The [meta] link is nestled in next to [about] and [faq] which are visited once or twice and then forgotten about. On a mature site this isn't a problem, but when young like us at present... Maybe we should ask them to move it back over next to the SE link at top left?